# "Start something" and "start on something"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I don't know when to use "start on" instead of "start", ıs there a difference in meaning if I omit "on" ?

> 1- We're ***starting a new book*** in class that's supposed to be
>   really interesting.
>
> 1a- We're ***starting on a new book*** in class that's supposed to be
>   really interesting.
>
> 2- He's just ***started a new job***.
>
> 2a- He's just ***started on a new job***
>
> 3- You’d better ***start on your homework***.
>
> 3a- You’d better ***start your homework***.
>
> 4- I'll get ***started on the dishes*** if you want to put the kids to
>   bed.
>
> 4a- I'll get ***started the dishes*** if you want to put the kids to
>   bed.

Is it possible to use the second versions of the examples ?

Comment: 4a isn't idiomatic - you either ***get started on** [process, object of attention]* or you ***get** [process] **started***. Or simply ***start** [process]*. Thus *I'll get started on the dishes, I'll get the dishes started,* or *I'll start the dishes*. All permutations except your version!

Comment: The others seem okay to you?

Comment: Yes. You can ***start [task]*** or ***start on [task]***, and you can ***get started on [task]***. But you can't ***get started [task]*** without including ***on***.

Answer (score 1):

*On X* can express X is a current topic or task.

> Today we will have a discussion on history.
>
> I am working on the unprocessed invoices.

The logic with *start on X* is that you are making X the current topic or task.